# yii2:jquery if gridview column contains specific value than change color

Tags: php, jquery, gridview, yii2

Let's say I have a column in my grid-view is_delivered, which contains array of values of for example

(1,1,0), (1,1,1),(0,0,0) that is three combinations in all. I have set the id of the cell as 'delivered'

Now how I can changed the color of the row for example red, blue or yellow depending on the value in the column.

like for example if it is (1,1,1)then row-color will be green, if (1,1,0) then row-color will be yellow and else red.

I cannot make it out where and how to start. I cannot use here == as it can contain more than 3 values. Need to use some operator like contains.

I am trying to use a simple code like

```
<?php      
$script = <<<EOD
alert ($('#delivered').val());

EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);        
?>
```

but it is giving me a blank alert without any value.

Thanks for any suggestion.

updating question for deriving values for column is_delivered

```
[
             'attribute'=>'is_delivered',             
            'value' => function ($data) {
                $str = '';
                foreach($data->medicineRequests as $request) {
                    $str .= $request->is_delivered.',';
                }
                return $str;

            },

        ],
```

So the column is_delivered is one to many and pulled from another model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do like below:

```
'attribute'=>'is_delivered',
'format'=>'raw',
'value'=>function($row){
      $values=[
      '(1,1,0)'=>'red',
      '(1,1,1)'=>'green',
      '(1,0,1)'=>'blue',
       //other values with its color
      ];
      return Html::tag('span', $row->is_delivered, ['style'=>'background-color:'.$values[$row->is_delivered]]);
}
```

By above code, we hold all of our possible values, and we assign a color to each one. Then, we show the value in a `span` tag, with the background color specified into `$values` array. Also, as you can see, there is no need to use `java-script`, or any `==` or `if` statements.

You can improve your code like below:

```
['style'=>'background-color:'.isset($values[$row->is_delivered]) ? $values[$row->is_delivered] : 'white']
```

So, if the value is not exist in `$values` array, it will show it with `white` background. Please note that, I set `background-color`, you must change it to `color` instead.

Comment: Hi Ali thanks for the suggestion, but there is a little problem as the combination may be 2 digit or 4 digits for example (1,1,1,1),(1,0,1,1),(0,0,0,0) similar. will it work in such cases.

Comment: Hi Ali, the column `is_delivered` is not the direct attribute of the table. I have updated the question. you have suggested one function for the value, where I am already using one function to pull the values. how to combine the both.

Comment: @Pawan Hi dear Pawan, Yes you can do it in your function. Just get the idea I wrote in my answer, so you can accomplish it.

Comment: Hi Ali, thanks, I think I can manage it,just a little hint as to how can I accomplish the background color of not just number but for the whole cell or whole row, if that is possible?